# How to delete trailing space after a table?

Tags: vba

I have a table

```
id sal
1  213
2  321
3  ..

(no data here)


     1 
N/A
```

I need to get rid of everything that goes after the table . I know that the table should end somewhere b/w rows 4000 - 6000 . Here is what i tried

```
Sub test()
For i = 4000 To 6000
    If Range("a" & i).Value = "" Then
        Range("A" & i).End(xlToRight).End(xlDown).Delete 'also tried Clear
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

However I got no effect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you wish to delete the entire row if the value for that Row in Column A is missing?

This one is very quick and very powerful:

```
Sub DeleteRowsWithBlankColumnA()
 [a:a].SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

We could try checking using the `IsEmpty()` function. Eg:

```
If IsEmpty(Range("A" & i)) Then
...
```